# Sharing folders between Windows XP and 8?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, windows-xp

so i'm trying to share folders between my 2 machines, an old XP desktop and a newer 8 laptop. i can access the shared folders on my XP from my 8 just fine through the good old ip search (ie. \192.168.0.x), but it doesn't seem to work the other way around. i can't for the life of me access my 8 machine through the ip search on my XP. what's wrong here:(? they're both connected to the same router, though different workgroups (didn't work when they were on the same workgroup as well)

thanks

Comment: first of all, can you ping each other?

Comment: thanks Bilo, but i finally solved it! it was really stupid. i just had to check-off _Turn on network discovery_, _Turn on file and printer sharing_, and _Turn off password protected sharing_ to bypass the login stuff under _Advanced sharing settings_ and voila!

Comment: I see, just to let you know if you want to use password protected sharing, under "File sharing connections" choose the option "40- or 56-bit encryption", as windows xp doesn't support 128 bit

Comment: ah gotcha thanks

let's say i do wanna use password protection, where do i setup the username/password?

Comment: it is based on your windows account password, press Ctrl + Alt + Del -> Change Password to setup a password

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just had to check-off Turn on network discovery, Turn on file and printer sharing, and Turn off password protected sharing to bypass the login stuff under Advanced sharing settings and voila!